# Make marker upside down in Android Google maps API V2

Tags: android, google-maps, rotation, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing app with Google Maps API 2 for Android and I need to rotate marker. Now I have this (red marker is the marker that I want to rotate when it is selected):[image: image1]

Okay, I can do the marker image rotation by rotating image with photoshop and than setting anchor for it:

[image: image1]

Everything looks almost fine, except that when I want to move this marker, it moves like it be pressed here:

[image: image1]

And if I look to coordinates, it gives me the bottom of the image coordinates, while I need the coordinates where the image top are pointing.

But I want to do, that marker moves when pressed on image, which is bellow marker point.

In short - is there are possible to rotate marker, that he will be like in second image and will be working like normal marker?

Sorry for my English, but I hope you get it.

Comment: 3rd image - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53529199/3.jpg

Comment: Show some code how you create this `Marker`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating marker, use `MarkerOptions.anchor(0.5f, 0.0f)`.

Comment: And after this, when I want to get marker position I will get coordinates from marker image top or from marker image bottom?